# How do I move my python (spyder) enviorment/ packages to another device?

Tags: python, spyder

I'm a complete novice- I took a python course a few years ago but forgot everything. I used spyder and have many packages etc. I'm now attempting to learn again on a new computer. How do I move my packages? Is there anything more I should move to make the transition and relearning as comfortable as possible? I have moved all my files as well.
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you *list* the packages you had installed on your old system, and download them anew on your new system. This is far better than copying, because it ensures compatibility and up-to-dateness.

The following is based on the assumption that you have `pip` available on your system(s). (If not, I can't help that much, but you could try the commands `conda list` and `conda install`.)

To list the packages that you have installed on your old system, type into the command line:

`pip list --user`

Also type the following – its outcome may or may not differ from the first list (because the first command, depending on your system, might refer to python2, whereas the second definitely refers to python3):

`pip3 list --user`

Save the two lists on your new computer. Go through the packages in the list one by one and install those you need or want to try.

Always make sure you are working with python3 (because python2 is heavily outdated). You can type `pip --version` to find out whether the command `pip` on your system refers to python2 or python3. If it refers to python2, the command to use is instead `pip3` (probably).